# How do I show the default information when the page loads rather than clicking on a marker for google maps, when info comes from kml file?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, addeventlistener

I am using the below tutorial to load the information in a kml file and show it to the right of Map.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features.html

In this tutorial, the right side info will populate on click of a particular marker. By default the right side is blank. How do I get to show the default information without click. I mean when the page loads it should show the info associated with the marker, that is the center point of the map. And later when the users click on other markers the info will change accordingly.

I tried using `tilesloaded` event but it doesn't work.

Bottom Line: how do I show the info without clicking the marker

Answer (score 0):

The KmlLayer object doesn't give access to KML features without a click. If you want to do that, you'll need to parse the KML separately. Since you're using jQuery, you could use parseXML:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: is there any other way to acheive this effect without using kml files

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you mean is there a way to create markers on a map without using JavaScript and to load that data into the side panel? Yes, you can do that. Just have your server send some JSON to your page and create both a marker and a side-panel.